# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
pip install matplotlib
```

I have already installed matplotlib in Jupyter notebook inside a new environment but whenever i'm writing

```
import matplotlib
```

It is generating an error 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual environment

```
pipenv install <module name>
```